# Change browser settings at startup in mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a .net mvc3 application, and I would like the browser to open without navigation, etc.

I tried using things like..

`winRef = window.open('@Url.Action("Index")', "IndexWindow", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=800, height=600")`;

etc, but the original browser window that opens always has the toolbar, menubar, etc already enabled.  Exactly where would I set the browser window attributes to the first window to open, already has these things disabled?

edit - A little more info, apparently I should have stated that this is for an internal application, and the menu bar, etc, just take up space.

Comment: xy problem. What are you trying to solve by attempting to hide navigation? First, it can't reliably be done; 2nd, you're not achieving anything, as user can still "go back a page" (for example) using the keyboard. Bad practice to hide toolbar; bad practice to popup windows - your usability suffers.

Comment: Hari - This is going to be an internal application, so the browser bars are not needed, and just take up space.   I also did not mention popups.  This can be done easily in a regular web application, but I can't figure out how in an mvc application.

Comment: `window.open` and you didn't mention popups? add that code to page-load on the client (javascript), on the home page, popup will open, but you won't be able to close the original window in at least one browser. Second, no, it cannot be done, or the behavior is the same on all websites, regardless of technology - it's the client/browser behavior, and the server-running code has nothing to do with it. It's up to the browser and per-user settings (dig into Firefox/IE settings, for example, and you'll find those that relate to showing toolbars in popups, and similar)

Comment: Voting this question down seems a bit absurd. it's a reasonable question. Seems that it's worth asking. it's not like he's saying, "um, guys, will you do my homework for me?"

Comment: Thanks MrBoJangles, I thought that was a little rude.  We have several apps in our company that open full screen without the toolbar, I don't know why it is ' bad practice' in Hari's mind, when he'll never have to use it, and it is exactly what the users are asking for.